# Banana Test Connector - Eagle

Tags: pcb-design, connector, eaglecad

I spend a lot of time trying to find these connectors in many different eagle libs, but without any success.

https://caltestelectronics.com/ctitem/91-jacks-banana-jacks/CT3151SP

[image]

http://www.newark.com/cliff-electronic-components/fcr7350l/banana-jack-4mm-r-a-24a-pcb-blue/dp/20T2057

[image]

Can you recommend any?

Answer (score 5):

If you can't quickly find a suitable footprint (or schematic symbol)  for a component in the CAD program's library, make the symbol and footprint yourself.  This applies to ALL CAD programs (Altium, KiCAD, Eagle, or whatever).  If you make the footprint yourself, you'll know that it does actually match the coponent you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As said @Peter Bennet, you easily make the footprint yourself. Eagle provide a very complete drawing service.

The trace for you connector can be found in the [download -> drawing tab](https://caltestelectronics.com/images/attachments/P315100rF_Drawing.pdf)

CT3151SP :

[image]

[FCR7350L S16N-PC Blue](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2161134.pdf?_ga=2.188775209.329008375.1497007801-1547248000.1497007801) :

[image]